# How can I mock a method of a Django model manager?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-mock

Here is a little class (in `myapp/getters.py`):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserGetter:
    def get_user(self):
        return User.objects.get(username='username')
```

I would like to mock out the call to `User.objects.get`, return a `MagicMock`, and test that the method returns what I injected. In `myapp/tests/tests_getters.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager
from mock import patch, create_autospec
from myapp.getters import UserGetter

class MockTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch('myapp.getters.User', autospec=True)
    def test(self, user_class):
        user = create_autospec(User)
        objects = create_autospec(UserManager)
        objects.get.return_value = user
        user_class.objects.return_value = objects
        self.assertEquals(user, UserGetter().get_user())
```

But when I run this test (with `python manage.py test myapp.tests.tests_getters`) I get

```
AssertionError:
  <MagicMock name='User.objects().get()' spec='User' id='4354507472'> !=
    <MagicMock name='User.objects.get()' id='4360679248'>
```

Why do I not get back the mock I injected? How can I write this test correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
user_class.objects.return_value = objects
```

You instruct the mock to have a function "objects" that returns the objects on the right side.
But your code never calls any objects() function. It accesses the User.objects property, User is a Mock here, so User returns a new Mock on property access.

Comment: That's it. The fix is to change `user_class.objects.return_value = objects` to `user_class.objects = objects`. It also works if I don't patch `User` and just assign to `User.objects`, but I suspect that would contaminate other tests.